# how to union two data frames so that every value in one data frame is linked to all values in another using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, union

For example, the data is:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'aa':[1,2,3]})
b=pd.DataFrame({'bb':[4,5]})
```

what I want is to union these two data frames so the new frame is :

```
aa    bb
1      4
1      5
2      4
2      5
3      4
3      5
```

You can see that every value in a is linked to all the values in b in the new frame. I probably can use tile or repeat to do this. But I have multiple frames which need to be done repeatedly. So I want to know if there is a better way?

Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
In [24]: a['key'] = 1

In [25]: b['key'] = 1

In [27]: pd.merge(a, b, on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
Out[27]: 
   aa  bb
0   1   4
1   1   5
2   2   4
3   2   5
4   3   4
5   3   5
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then `reset_index`. It is generating all the combinations between both set of data (the same idea than [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product))

```
df_outut = (pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a.aa,b.bb],names=['aa','bb']))
              .reset_index())
```

and you get

```
   aa  bb
0   1   4
1   1   5
2   2   4
3   2   5
4   3   4
5   3   5
```